# Convert directory to QEMU/KVM virtual disk image

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have a directory filled with data at `/var/backups/disk1` that I want to convert into a virtual disk image which I'll then be able to boot using QEMU or KVM (the directory contains the file system for a virtual machine, copied out via rsync).

While there are plenty of instructions out there for converting a complete physical disk to a virtual disk, packaging up only the contents of a single directory into a virtual disk image is turning out to be much more difficult than I expected.  Any ideas?

By the way, I know I can use `qemu-img` to convert a block device into a virtual disk (e.g., `qemu-img convert -f /dev/sdc -O qcow2 disk.qcow2`), so if only I could get the directory `/var/backups/disk1` to appear to be a block device, then theoretically I should be able to accomplish my goal using `qemu-img`. I've thought about creative ways to expose the directory as a block device using NBD or a loopback device, however, and have not had success.

Answer (score 20):

First, create a raw image of the required size. I'll assume 10G is enough. Using *seek* creates a [sparse file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file), which saves space.

```
dd if=/dev/null of=example.img bs=1M seek=10240
```

Next, create a filesystem on it.

```
mkfs.ext4 -F example.img
```

(Note that you need the `-F` option for `mkfs.ext4` to operate on a file as opposed to a disk partition)

Then, mount it.

```
mkdir /mnt/example
mount -t ext4 -o loop example.img /mnt/example
```

Now you can copy your files to /mnt/example. Once this is done, unmount it and you can use example.img as a drive in a virtual machine. If you want you can convert it from a raw image to another format like qcow2e using qemu-img, but this isn't required.

Comment: `qemu-img` and `fallocate` are a slightly more convenient than `dd`.

Comment: How to calculate the minimum required size: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/353156/how-to-calculate-the-correct-size-of-a-loopback-device-filesystem-image-for-debo

Answer (score 5):

Seems like libguestfs can do it, see [virt-make-fs(1)](http://libguestfs.org/virt-make-fs.1.html) and maybe [virt-copy-in(1)](http://libguestfs.org/virt-copy-in.1.html).

Answer (score 5):

**`virt-make-fs` from libguestfs `qcow2` example**

https://serverfault.com/a/332114/163884 mentioned it, but here is a full example:

```
sudo apt-get install libguestfs-tools

# Workarounds for Ubuntu 18.04 bugs. See section below.
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/.guestfs-*
echo dash | sudo tee /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/zz-dash-packages
sudo chmod +r /boot/vmlinuz-*

mkdir sysroot
# Just a test file.
dd if=/dev/urandom of=sysroot/myfile bs=1024 count=1024
virt-make-fs --format=qcow2 --type=ext2 sysroot sysroot.ext2.qcow2
```

Note how `sudo` is not required, except for installation and Ubuntu bug workarounds.

I then verified that QEMU can actually read it with:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -drive file=sysroot.ext2.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=virtio,snapshot ...
```

I am then able to mount the image inside QEMU Linux and read the file.

**`virt-make-fs` ext example**

This awesome tool can also make raw ext filesystems, e.g.:

```
virt-make-fs --format=raw --type=ext2 sysroot sysroot.ext2
virt-make-fs --format=raw --type=ext4 sysroot sysroot.ext4
```

which we can verify directly on the host with:

```
mkdir -p mnt
dev="$(sudo losetup --show -f -P sysroot.ext4)"
sudo mount -o loop "$dev" mnt
cmp sysroot/myfile mnt/myfile
```

**Image size minimization**

A really good feature of `virt-make-fs` is that it automatically tries to minimize the image size if that is what we want:

> Virt-make-fs defaults to minimizing the extra space, but you can use the --size flag to leave space in the filesystem if you want it.

so:

```
df -h
```

tells me that the image is 82% filled:

```
/dev/loop17    1.5M  1.1M  244K  82% /home/ciro/test/guestfs/mnt
```

We can easily add some extra space on top of the minimum with `--size-=+`:

```
virt-make-fs --format=raw --size=+8M --type=ext2 sysroot sysroot.ext2
```

**ext4 journal overhead**

The manual also mentions that:

> Note that ext3 filesystems contain a journal, typically 1-32 MB in size. If you are not going to use the filesystem in a way that requires the journal, then this is just wasted overhead.

and it is interesting to verify that with:

```
du -bs *
```

which produces:

```
1052672 sysroot
1446297 sysroot.ext2
2599731 sysroot.ext4
```

so we see that the ext4 came out significantly bigger.

**libguestfs Ubuntu bugs**

Now for the downside: there appears to be [no Ubuntu maintainer currently](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1591617#c4) and the library is generally buggy on Ubuntu.

`sudo` is not in theory required, but it is required due to an Ubuntu packaging bug unless we do a workaround: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046828/how-to-run-libguestfs-tools-tools-such-as-virt-make-fs-without-sudo/1046829#1046829

```
libguestfs: error: /usr/bin/supermin exited with error status 1.
To see full error messages you may need to enable debugging.
Do:
  export LIBGUESTFS_DEBUG=1 LIBGUESTFS_TRACE=1
and run the command again.  For further information, read:
  http://libguestfs.org/guestfs-faq.1.html#debugging-libguestfs
You can also run 'libguestfs-test-tool' and post the *complete* output
into a bug report or message to the libguestfs mailing list.
    libguestfs: error: /usr/bin/supermin exited with error status 1.
```

After that, without our workarounds, 18.04 (but not 16.04) fails with: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1591617

```
libguestfs: error: tar_in: write error on directory: /:
```

due to a bug that was already fixed upstream.

Tested in Ubuntu 18.04, libguestfs-tools 1:1.36.13-1ubuntu3, QEMU 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.3.

Answer (score 1):

Using Michaels strategy in Fedora 23:

```
# dnf install -y libguestfs-tools-c
# virt-make-fs --format=raw --label mylabel the_directory myfs.raw
```

This creates ext2 file system, that you can mount to some directory:

```
# mount file.fs /mnt
```

Now /mnt contains all your files

Comment: If `file.fs` is a file, shouldn't the `mount` command be: `mount -o loop file.fs /mnt`?

Answer (score 0):

What about accessing the directory as a network share from a VM that is also mounted to your target virtual disk image? You than than just perform a simple copy from the share to the mounted disk image.

Comment: That should work, and is similar to my current strategy, which is to build a VM and rsync the data in.  It would be great if there were a quicker and cleaner solution, though.  Copying the data into a new machine gets pretty messy because you have to worry about making sure you exclude certain files that shouldn't be copied, like fstab and most things in /boot

Comment: "exclude certain files that shouldn't be copied, like fstab and most things in /boot" - may not be that much of an issue when the VM target is an additional volume.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer (and use) the answer by Ciro Santilli, but here's something that works with a `guestfish` shell:

```
# assumes extant directory "rootfs"
tar -cf rootfs.tar -C rootfs .
guestfish <<EOF
disk-create rootfs.qcow2 qcow2 "$((2 * $(stat -c%s rootfs.tar)))"
add-drive rootfs.qcow2
run
part-disk /dev/sda gpt
mkfs ext4 /dev/sda
mount /dev/sda /
tar-in rootfs.tar /
umount-all
exit
EOF
```